# How to only get unque documents in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code is giving the same user document multiple times if the same user user_id is there multiple times in Order collection, So how to fix this? and only get one document for that user who has multiple orders? any mongoose method to do that?

```js
router.post('/getusers', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      orderID
    } = req.body;

    const order = await Order.findById(orderID).populate({
      path: 'orders',
      populate: {
        path: 'user_id',
        model: 'User',
        select: 'name',
      },
    });

    if (!order) {
      return res.status(404).send('order not found');
    }

    const response = order.orders.map((order: any) => ({
      user_id: order.user_id._id.toString(),
      name: order.user_id.name,
      order: order.order,
    }));

    console.log(response);

    res.status(200).json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

});
```

Comment: how do you determine which one to retrieve? is there a sort in your payload or business logic like asc or desc?

Comment: @sid I mean like there is a Orders collection in my db,  so based on orederid it gets that order document and inside that order document there is orders array inside that there are user_id of users with some text which is order like a note so how to get all those user name from there _id i mean all users

Answer (score 0):

To get unique user documents based on their `user_id` when you have multiple orders for the same user, you can use the `$group` stage in a Mongoose aggregation pipeline. This stage will help you group orders by `user_id` and then project only the unique user documents. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
router.post('/getusers', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { orderID } = req.body;

    const aggregationPipeline = [
      {
        $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderID) },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$orders',
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$orders.user_id',
          user_id: { $first: '$orders.user_id' }, // Keep the user_id
          name: { $first: '$orders.user_id.name' }, // Keep the user's name
          orders: { $push: '$orders.order' }, // Collect orders in an array
        },
      },
    ];

    const order = await Order.aggregate(aggregationPipeline);

    if (!order || order.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send('Order not found');
    }

    res.status(200).json(order);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

1. start with a `$match` stage to filter for the specific order based on its `_id`.
2. Then, we use the `$unwind` stage to deconstruct the orders array so that each order becomes a separate document.
3. The $group stage is used to group the orders by `user_id`. We keep the `user_id` and `user_id.name` from the first order within each group and collect all orders associated with the same user into an array.
4. This aggregation pipeline will give you a result where each user appears only once, and their orders are collected in an array under the orders field. This way, you get a list of unique users with their associated orders.

Make sure to adjust the code as needed to match your schema and data structure.